# New to C# - trying to write code to do a simple function

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm new to C# (worked in PHP, Python, and Javascript) and I'm trying to more or less make a duplicate of another page and change some things - to make a form and database submission.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
public partial class commenter : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string employee_reviewed;
    //public Commenter();
    public void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommentTB.Text == "Please enter a comment.")
        {
            String csname = "Email Error";
            Type cstype = this.GetType();
            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname))
            {
                String cstext = "alert('Please submit at least one comment.');";
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, cstext, true);
            }
            FormMessage.Text = "Please submit at least one comment.";
            return;
        }
        string comment = CommentTB.Text;
        comment = comment.Replace("'", "''");
        comment = comment.Replace("’", "''");
        comment = comment.Replace("`", "''");

        try
        {
            //myCommand.Connection.Open();
            //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //myCommand.Connection.Close();

            MySqlCommand myCommand;
            MySqlConnection connection;
            string connStringName = "server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connStringName);

            string sql_query;


            sql_query = "insert into peer_review_comment " + " (emp_id,  comment)" + " values(?employeeid, ?comment) ";

            //String csname = "Email Error";
            //Type cstype = this.GetType();
            //ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            //cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, sql_query, true);
            myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql_query, connection);
            //FormMessage.Text = sql_query;
            //return;

            Trace.Write("comment = ", comment);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?employeeid", ViewState["employeeid"].ToString()));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?comment", comment));

            try
            {
                myCommand.Connection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myCommand.Connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FormMessage.Text = "Error:SaveBtn_Click - " + ex.Message;
            }
            //SendNotification(from, to, cc, subject, body, attach);
            FormMessage.Text = "\n Thank you for leaving anonymous feedback for " + employee_reviewed; ;
            ThankyouDiv.Visible = true;
            FormFieldDiv.Visible = false;
            reviewHeader.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FormMessage.Text = "Error:SaveBtn_Click - " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

I really have little idea what I'm doing - I'm reading the tutorials, but C# is a significantly different language than I am used to.

I get the Javascript alert when I do not change the text currently, but submission isn't working - I want it to submit to `peer_review_comment` database table, and fill in employeeid as well as the submitted comment.

Sorry if my understanding is so spotty, I am a TOTAL C# newbie (currently reading http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/)

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: Use validators for validation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Comment: Do you get an exception?  Reading up on using the debugger would be valuable also.

Comment: Clicking the submit button doesn't seem to actually submit anything to the database.

I get no exception, and for some reason the debugger is grayed out (I am using MS Visual Web Developer 2010 express - I'm writing something for ASP.NET). I should also mention - I am unfamiliar with .NET as well.

Comment: did you associate the method SaveBtn_Click with the OnClick of the asp button control?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="SaveBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" onClick="SaveBtn_Click" CssClass="submit_btn" />

Comment: If you remove the Try / catch do you get an exception?

Comment: Also no need to have 2 try/catch blocks. Just keep the outer one, and remove the inner try/catch. And as a sidenote, have a look at MS WebSiteSpark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is the problem is here:

```
try
{
    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCommand.Connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    FormMessage.Text = "Error:SaveBtn_Click - " + ex.Message;
    // no "return;"  !!
}
//SendNotification(from, to, cc, subject, body, attach);
FormMessage.Text = "\n Thank you for leaving anonymous feedback for " + 
                        employee_reviewed; ;
```

Your `catch` block is setting the `FormMessage.Text` value bot not exiting the method, so the method keeps executing where the catch block finishes off, resetting the `Text` value and appearing that no exception was thrown.

add a `return;` at the end of your catch block to see the excpetion message.

Some general guidelines to make these kinds of problems easier to trap:

- Don't try to do too much in one method.  Have one method that validates the message (or do it client-side using `Validators`, another to do the DB call, etc.
- Learn to use the debugger.  You can step through code and get a better idea of what causes these kinds of errors.
- Unless you can DO something about an exception, there's no harm in letting them bubble up to a higher level event handler (like [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)) so exceptions don't get accidentally swallowed like it does here.  In general it's preferrable to re-throw exceptions in lower-level methods (maybe adding some context or a user-friendly message) so the higher level exception handling can decide what to do (show a message, log, etc.)

Comment: Not getting an exception message. It's just looking like it reloads the page (but the text inside the text box isn't changed, so I do not believe it is), and no error is thrown.

Comment: Because your catch blocks are "swallowing" the exception instead of re-throwing it or a new one.  remove the try/catch blocks and see what happens

Comment: There we go. You guys are beautiful. Now that I have an exception, I should be able to fix it.

Comment: Yep, I got it. It's working now. There was a bad parameter with my database insert.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the liberty of refactoring your code.  This shows some better code practices but may also show you the problem.  Along with these code changes I would also recommend reading D. Stanley's answer; there are some helpful tips in there as well.

```
if (CommentTB.Text == "Please enter a comment.") 
{ 
    String csname = "Email Error"; 
    Type cstype = this.GetType(); 
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript; 
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname)) 
    { 
        String cstext = "alert('Please submit at least one comment.');"; 
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, cstext, true); 
    } 
    FormMessage.Text = "Please submit at least one comment."; 
    return; 
} 

// This helps some but very little, just wanted to show an alternative to writing three statements
string comment = CommentTB.Text.Replace("'", "''").Replace("’", "''").Replace("`", "''"); 
//string comment = CommentTB.Text; 
//comment = comment.Replace("'", "''"); 
//comment = comment.Replace("’", "''"); 
//comment = comment.Replace("`", "''"); 


try 
{ 
    // No need to do string concatenation...just make it one string.
    // sql_query = "insert into peer_review_comment " + " (emp_id,  comment)" + " values(?employeeid, ?comment) "; 
    string sql_query = "insert into peer_review_comment (emp_id,  comment) values (?employeeid, ?comment) "; 

    string connStringName = "server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password"; 

    // Use a "using" clause because it guarantees the connection is closed even when an exception occurs.
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStringName)) 
    {
        connection.Open(); 

        // Again, use a "using" clause
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql_query, connection)) 
        {
            Trace.Write("comment = ", comment); 
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?employeeid", ViewState["employeeid"].ToString())); 
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?comment", comment)); 
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

            // No need for a Close statement with "using" clause.
            //myCommand.Connection.Close(); 
        }
    } 

    FormMessage.Text = "\n Thank you for leaving anonymous feedback for " + employee_reviewed;
    ThankyouDiv.Visible = true; 
    FormFieldDiv.Visible = false; 
    reviewHeader.Visible = false; 
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    FormMessage.Text = "Error:SaveBtn_Click - " + ex.Message; 
}
```